# Which options can i use with gulp-pug?

Tags: html, gulp, pug

I have used gulp.js for a while, and while using the gulp-pug package I don't know which options can I use.

Let's use sass as an example:

// STYLES TASK

```
`gulp.task('style', function() {
  return gulp.src(['public/style/libs/*.*', 'public/style/sass/app-root.scss'])
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass.sync().on('error', sass.logError)) ======>#1
    .pipe(prefix())  ======>#2
    .pipe(concat('app-style.css'))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('../../public/maps'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'))
})`
```

I'm talking here about adding option like `#1, #2`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any options from [Pug's API](https://pugjs.org/api/reference.html) in addition to pug's own options.

you can find  more information about which options you can use with this package [here](https://github.com/gulp-community/gulp-pug#readme)

usage example:

```
var pug = require('gulp-pug');

gulp.task('views', function buildHTML() {
  return gulp.src('views/*.pug')
  .pipe(pug({
    // Your options in here. for example:

      doctype: 'html',
      pretty: false

  }))
});
```